# Is Eventhub message's enqueue time unique?

Tags: azure, primary-key, azure-eventhub

I routed incoming iot-hub message to Blob Storage. Then, messages will be parsed and stored in to SQL database.
I plan to use: EnqueueTime as primary key, so is Eventhub message's enqueue time unique?
Here is an example of enqueue time: 2019-10-29T04:32:54.6770000Z

Thanks.

Comment: Risky strategy IMO, if you need a surrogate key you could use the `MessageId`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no MessageId in blob file.

Comment: it won't be in the payload of the message, it will be in the metadata, it does exist though. Also, do you intend on using the ID for any other reason other than having a unique surrogate key? If not, then I'd just generate a random UUID instead e.g. [NEWID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks James, I think UUID is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using TimeStamp for any system as a unique identifier is risk idea. You can use the [messageId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct) OR [sequence-number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct) of the IOT hub message properties or You should generate a new property named Id which is unique before you are storing to blob storage.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Unfortunately, there is no unique field in blob file.